# How to move Azure functions from App Service plan to Consumption Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

At some point in the past I moved 3 Azure Function Apps from consumption into and App Service plan.

I'd now like to move those 3 functions into their own separate consumption plans but I can't figure out how to do that.

It seems there are instructions for going from consumption to app service but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few limitations when migrating to another App Service Plan (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#plan-migration) article):

- Direct migration to a Dedicated (App Service) plan isn't currently supported.
- Migration isn't supported on Linux.
- The source plan and the target plan must be in the same resource group and geographical region.
- The specific CLI commands depend on the direction of the migration.
- Downtime in your function executions occur as the function app is migrated between plans.
- State and other app-specific content is maintained, since the same Azure Files share is used by the app both before and after migration.

Here's a working example on how to move between plans.

> note that consumption plans cannot be created seperatly using AZ CLI,
> as mentionned over [HERE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11195)

```
#variable block
region="<region>"
resourceGroup="<resourceGroupName>"
functionApp="<myfunctionname>"
storageAccount="<storageAccountName"
storageSKU="Standard_LRS"
premiumPlan="<premiumPlanName>"
premiumPlanSKU="EP1"
consumptionPlan="<consumptionPlanName>"
functionRuntime="dotnet"
functionsVersion=4

#create resource group
az group create --name $resourceGroup --location $region

#create storage
az storage account create --name $storageAccount --location $region --    resource-group $resourceGroup --sku $storageSKU

#create functionapp using consumption plan
az functionapp create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $functionApp --consumption-plan-location $region --runtime $functionRuntime --functions-version $functionsVersion --storage-account $storageAccount

#create premium plan
az functionapp plan create --name $premiumPlan --resource-group $resourceGroup --location $region --sku $premiumPlanSKU

#move to premium plan 
az functionapp update --name $functionApp --resource-group $resourceGroup --plan $premiumPlan

#move to consumption plan
az functionapp update --name $functionApp --resource-group $resourceGroup --plan $consumptionPlan --force
```